# why can't I create multiple branches in a new, empty repository?

Tags: git, repository, branch

[Last Try Before solving Problem: shows the line which dont recognition the Mother Branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrYKO.jpg)

[four first lines of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue0Y0.jpg)

Here is The Code:

First i initialized a repo:

```
   $ git init
```

then renamed Master to Mother:

```
$ git branch -m "Mother"
```

created a readme.md:

```
 $ touch "readme.md"
```

The First error when i tried to create a new branch then, I got caught in it was(exactly is shown in the first image):

```
 $ git branch Product
    
    fatal: not a valid object name: 'Mother'
```

after creating several branches by alt:

```
   $ git checkout -b Product
    
    Switched to a new branch 'Product'
```

and commiting the readme.md file..

i tried to switch to The previously created branches but the main question is here:

```
   $  git checkout Product
    
    error: pathspec 'Product' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

this even happened for my Root:

```
$ git checkout Mother

error: pathspec 'Mother' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

so i recreated those branches again:

```
  $ git checkout -b Product
    
    Switched to branch 'Product'
```

**The Problem Solved but whats the reason behind it**

*may you tell me why?*

new edit: 'im intern'

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

Comment: ok thanks i do so as you said

Comment: i had several Irrelevant lines of code between em, as i tried several ways to solve it,  in the final version which i posted on the stackoverflow i didnt mentioned em

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Branches in Git are pointers to existing commits. When you `init`, your repository has 0 commits, thus you cannot create any branches. Once you have a commit, you can create new branches.

Comment: thx so why after i commited my readme file then i tried to return to my mother branch i got an error again (last image)

Comment: i think i got the answer i commited what file was in the mother branch in another branch(Client) so i think other branches deleted and Client Left Firmly! Thats what i reached to it i hope someone try to pull me out of this if its wrong / i touched a file in branch "Mother", but when i checkout to newly created branch by $ git checkout -b Client Command, then i commited what i did not commit before in Mother branch.  i try to figure it out

Comment: @میمشین Because there is no branch until you create your first commit. When you first do `git checkout -b YourBranch` the virtual branch "main" (or, in your case, "Mother") is gone, because it never existed. Branches can only exist when there is a commit for them to point to

Comment: woooow thanks very much, i dont haave enough rep to vote up sorry / i reached to it nearly too